# Frame size iOS8 Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I am a SpriteKit beginner and did some tutorials under iOS7 and xcode5. The frame size is now, after the update to xcode6 and iOS8, fix for every device (1024,768). My questions is now how can I actually figure our what is shown in the Scene and in which range the nodes are presented in the scene. (the actual size and range of the scene)
Example: node.position  = CGPointMake(0, 768); //cannot be seen in the scene whereas
         node.position  = CGPointMake(300, 768); //can be slightly seen in the scene

Thank you very much and kind regards,
SirSandmann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill` as the `scaleMode` for the scene it will scale proportionally until it fills the whole screen, so you will lose a bit from top and bottom of that size (1024,768) on 16:9 devices. The usable size of the scene for that aspect ratio (iPhone 5 and up) should be (1024,575) so that should be the area where important game elements should be placed.

If you want to support 3:2 devices (iPhone 4S and down) usable area should be (862,575) if I'm correct.

Comment: I found a solution for my question. The technical terms were the problem. I was confused by the different bounds of the devices. For every device is now the view and the scene with the size 768,1024, but the bound is different for every device. So i added in the GameViewController: 
 scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
to get back that the scene is just the size of the bounds.
What for disadvantages does it could have to go back to this option?

Comment: Well, if you use absolute positions elements will look different on iPad and iPhone devices. A node at 200,200 will obviously not be on the same position on a (1024,768) and on a (480,320) scene so you will have to use relative positions.

With the same scene size for all devices you don't need to worry about that as it will look the same. Just about the usable area so that it's playable on all devices.